# Create soft link to Google Drive folder on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nautilus, cloud, symbolic-link, google-drive, webdav

I'm trying to create a soft link to a Google Drive folder in Ubuntu 19.10.
I've just installed GNOME online account and I can browse it from Nautilus.
I remember that in a previous version of Ubuntu, I've created a soft link in my home folder to a specific folder in my Google Drive account, but I don't remember how.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIS, the Google Drive file paths are something like `/run/user/<your_local_user_id>/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=<your_google_user>/0B-xxx...xxx` where `xxx...xxx` is a long string of random characters. So, it is not very useful from command line. I would love to see some explanation on how to use them also.